# How to show an image instead of a SCNSphere in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am creating an app where I have a SCNSphere showing, but for some reason I tried figuring it out how to put an image from my assets instead of using the built in geometry that Apple has. So, my question is how can I show a image showing in my SceneKit app instead of the SCNSphere. 
Thanks for any help.

```
let personGeo = SCNSphere(radius: 0.2)
person = SCNNode(geometry: personGeo)

let personMat = SCNMaterial()
personMat.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
personGeo.materials = [personMat]
person.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 1.1, 0)


person.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(node: person, options: nil))
person.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bodyNames.Person
person.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = bodyNames.Coin
person.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = bodyNames.Coin
person.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(person)
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? In order to change the kind of object displayed by SceneKit you must set personGeo to another kind of SCNGeometry, for instance SCNPlane

Comment: what I want to do is instead of putting the built in geometry, I want to put an image from my assets to show. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your node to be rendered by SceneKit it must first of all have geometry data (see `SCNGeometry` class) attached to it.

SceneKit already provides for you a handful of those for you, with `SCNPlane` you can use a plane to display the image you want.

You must then give to your node a material that will display the image.

Something similar to this probably:

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
let image = UIImage(named: "nameOfYourImage")!
let imageRatio = image.size.height / image.size.width
let desiredPlaneWidth: CGFloat = 1
let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: desiredPlaneWidth, height: desiredPlaneWidth*imageRatio) // We make a plane that has the same aspect ratio as the image we want to display with it
let planeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
planeMaterial.emission.contents = image // Emission makes 
planeMaterial.isDoubleSided = true // Otherwise plane would only be visible from one side
```

Don't hesitate to ask for specific details

Comment: can you show me some code to apply `SCNPlane` to display a image?

Comment: @user8651879 I updated my answer on how to create the material and the plane ! :)

Comment: @user8651879 You are welcome ! Don't forget to accept and up vote answers if they helped you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a SCNSphere create an SCNPlane, add a SCNMaterial to it and set its .diffuse.contents to the image.

Also, to make sure the image faces the camera, add a LookAt constraint to the SCNPlane node to make it look at the camera (target is pointOfView node of the sceneview).